# text box output method or data member not found

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Hi all   I have please see code below.

```
Private Sub Command6_Click() 
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord 
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew 
Me.Parent![seznam kusu k mìøení].Form.Requery 
On Error GoTo handler    
Dim frm As Form    
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset        
Set frm = Me.[seznam kusu k mìøení].Form    
Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone
    With rst
       If Not .EOF Then .MoveLast
          Me.tbSubformRecordCount = .RecordCount   ' <- Error
       .Close
    End With
    Exit Sub handler: 
End Sub
```

I cannot figuret out what i am doing wrong. But i still recieve error (Method or data member not found) for  `<- Error`.
Could you tell me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: If you wish to get a count of subform records, why not use count in the form footer?

Comment: Are you missing a `.` in your line at `Me.tbSubForm.RecordCount` or is that a typo?

Comment: No it is nane of text box where i want to display counted value. And why i need to do that ? This subform acting like samples for curent id overwiev. So user is creating measurements record from another subform and that subform display them. What i want to do is once there is lats say 5 records i will perform some another action

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions / suggestions...

- Does your form contain a subform? It appears to be yes based on the code requerying the PARENT
- Based on assumption #1, then is the button located on the subdorm?
- Depending on answers, I think I can provide a solution.
- Set frm = Forms![ParentForm]![MySubForm].Form  will point to the subform

Comment: This textbox is located in main form and should get count number from thah subform

Comment: The line with the error is wrong but where is your code... main or subform... it makes a big difference. You need to do something like me.txtreccount = .record count if code on main (but then you would be using wrong Set frm...). If code in subform you need me.parent.txtreccnt = .record count

Comment: OK, I just created a subform with a rowset containing 26 records. Then created a main form (no recordset) and in the detail section I placed three controls: (1) subform; (2) txt box; (3) Cmd button. I used your code, with following changes: 1. changedg subform name; 2. removed first 3 lines (Save, goto, requery) and the code ran just fine.
I didn't use header or footer on main form, but that should not matter. Put a breakpoint where you get error; go to immediate window and try to reference the values of .recordset and tbSubformRecordCount at least that will narrow down which one it is.